# How to effectively create controller or model without using php artisan?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

Why must i use php artisan to create controller or model in laravel. Can i not just use the IDE to create a blank controller or model class?

Comment: You can do it however you want. You can just create a blank file and name it correctly. The reason why you should artisan is that it helps you to setup everything much faster. You won't miss any configuration if you use the commands provided by your framework. (Not just for creating controller, but for everything!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure you could just make your Controllers and Models by hand, but its pretty convenient to use php artisan.

Pretty much all IDE's have support for snippets. You could make snippets for controllers and models.

**Controller example snippet**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class YourController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {

    }

}
```

**Model example snippet**

```
<?php
class ModelExample extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'model_table';


}
```

I prefer and highly recommend using php artisan instead of using your IDE's snippets-feature.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you may use the IDE and create everything from scratch. It's just to help and speed things up.